# Can you force a compiler warning or error in Kotlin/Java?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Having a background in iOS development, I'm quite used to using this directive for intentionally triggering a compiler warning (in Swift):

```swift
#warning("This will output as a warning during compilation")
```

or this one to trigger an error:

```swift
#error("This will output as an error during compilation")
```

This is very useful if, for example, I need to defer attention to the code fragment in question, or when using conditional compiler directives. I really miss this feature during Android development (in Kotlin, preferably, but I'm also curious about a similar Java feature).

I'd like to know if there's at least an alternative for doing this, especially if it's integrated well into Android Studio and the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party here, but for that specific case, `TODO` comments are great. They are just like any other comment, but Android Studio (and IntelliJ for that matter) will highlight them differently and there's a special TODO window available that shows all the TODO-comments in the file or project. Here's an example:

```
// TODO This will be hightlighted by Android Studio
```

Comment: Better late than never! That's what I ended up doing, too. However, I found that Android Studio is sometimes unreliable in picking up TODOs and FIXMEs scattered around the codebase. Plus, it's easy to forget to look into the TODO tab when you don't have a habit of doing so. Still, this does not allow to produce errors. Just as well, `#error`s in Swift can have flexible conditions; for example, you can wrap it with `#if DEBUG`/`#endif` so that it only produces a compiler error when building a Release version). I guess some fiddling with Gradle or kapt could replicate this feature (never tried).

Comment: Also, if you use a linter (like KtLint), you could create a rule that triggers on TODOs and FIXMEs. Otherwise, if you have some sort of issue-, bug- or ticket-system, you could instead just create a ticket and assign it to yourself, reminding you about the todo :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about throwing an exception: `throw new Exception("Exception message");` this is for Java. For Kotlin it's similar with a little change :[Kotlin nothing exception](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type)

Comment: This can only be thrown at runtime?

Comment: Yes. Here is compiler time : Log.e(String, String) (error)
Log.w(String, String) (warning)
Log.i(String, String) (information)
Log.d(String, String) (debug)
Log.v(String, String) (verbose)

Comment: @AhmetKorkmaz Please clarify. I assume that these are Logcat methods and I was pretty sure they're useful for logging at runtime only. And yes, I'm also certain that `Exception`s are used for runtime errors.

Comment: Yes logging is also runtime, I have no experience in Swift but I presume the OP is specifically looking to generate compiler warnings.

Comment: @HenryTwist Your assumptions are, indeed, correct.